# Associated type conforming to Protocol and dependency injection issues

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I am researching dependency injection and am currently in the process of updating my project to make use of it. However, I am having issues with associated type and protocol conforming.

I have created a quick demo project and I have created a few protocols and extensions so that viewControllers that conform to my protocol ViewModelBased must implement an associatedtype. Ideally I want this associatedtype to conform to a viewModel. Here is what I have so far

```
protocol ViewModel {
    associatedtype Services
    init (withServices services: Services)
}

protocol ViewModelBased: class {
    associatedtype ViewModelType
    var viewModel: ViewModelType { get set }
}

extension ViewModelBased where Self: UIViewController{
    static func instantiateController(with viewModel : ViewModelType) -> Self {

        // I have created UIStoryboard extension to allow for easy opening of view controllers
        // in storyboard
        let viewController : Self = UIStoryboard.mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController()
        viewController.viewModel = viewModel
        return viewController
    }
}
```

So all viewModels in my app conform to ViewModel which forces them to implement a service type. For example, my LoginModel looks like this

```
 struct LoginModel : ViewModel{

    // service type
    typealias Services = LoginService

    // init service
    var services : LoginService
    init(withServices services: LoginService) {
        self.services = services
    }

    /// calls login service - attempts login api
    func attemptLogin() {
        services.login()
    }
}
```

So here is an example of a viewController that implements this

```
class SecondController: UIViewController, ViewModelBased  {

    var viewModel: LoginModel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func loginTest() {
        viewModel.services.onLoginSuccess = { isVerified in

            print(isVerified)
        }

        viewModel.services.onLoginFailure = { errorCode in

            print(errorCode)
        }

        viewModel.attemptLogin()
    }
}
```

So putting this together, this allows the app to init a viewController and pass in a viewModel like this

```
   let loginModel = LoginModel(withServices: LoginService())
        let controller = SecondController.instantiateController(with: loginModel)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

This all works very well, but the problem I am having is, the associated Type can be any type at the moment. Ideally I want this associatedType to conform to the ViewModel protocol. However when I try this

```
protocol ViewModelBased: class {
    associatedtype ViewModelType : ViewModel
    var viewModel: ViewModelType { get set }
}
```

My SecondController now throws an error and now forces me to init the LoginModel

```
var viewModel : LoginModel = LoginModel(withServices: LoginService())
```

But this is no longer making use of dependency injection as the viewController is now in charge of creating the viewModel instance and knows about the behavior of the viewModel class.

Is there a way I can fix this? Would be very grateful if someone could give me some information on what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You could extend `Optional` to conditionally conform to `ViewModel`:

```
extension Optional: ViewModel where Wrapped: ViewModel {

    typealias Services = Wrapped.Services

    init(withServices services: Services) {
        self = Wrapped(withServices: services)
    }

}
```

Now your `SecondController` declares its model as `var viewModel: LoginModel?`, which it initializes to `nil` by default, while still ensuring that its `ViewModelType` is a `ViewModel` without actually needing to create an instance of it.

Comment: This is an interesting solution but it means the viewModels are now optional so have to unwrap viewModel every time it is called. I was hoping I could avoid something like this.

Comment: What version of Swift are you using? I am using the latest development snapshot to try out your code and it doesn't compile for `viewModel` being implicitly unwrapped, because an IUO can't be used to fulfill a non-optional protocol requirement (this was possible in pre 4.1 versions, I have tried it in 4.0.3 and it works). So this is probably a change you need to make anyway.

Comment: I am using the latest Swift 4.1 and the code I posted compiles just fine for me. Interesting that it is not compiling for you.